# Bean Validation with args condition

Tags: java, bean-validation

Let's assume this situation.

I have `length` label. Sometimes I want it to show me the message `Length must be lower than 5!`, but other time it should show `Length must be value between 2 and 5!`. It should depend on number of arguments I pass to this.

Could it be done without using second label, for instance `Length`?

Comment: Is this Swing or something? What do you mean by label? Is it a GUI problem?

Comment: It's actually property in messages.properties file

Comment: I still do not understand what you are using. Are you using Spring? Struts? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: I use Spring. Do you need sth else?

Comment: If Bogdan Emil Mariesan didn't answer your question, you could post a snippet of your code where you call the label.

Comment: How do you configure the constraints? Bean Validation? You need to show your configured bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done without different values in your property file.

For e.g. you could have your label as such:

```
my.label=Length must be lower than 5!,Length must be value between 2 and 5!
```

But this is **NOT** recommended. You need to split it based on your separator, comma in this case, and handle that logic yourself.

The clean solution would be:

```
my.label.error.maxsize=Length must be lower than 5!
my.label.error.size=Length must be between 2 and 5!
```

And of course the value maxsize or size can be set programatically.

**EDIT:**

The java implementation depends a lot on the framework used to load values from property files.